# How to Configure CORS between an API hosted on AWS ElasticBeanstalk and the frontend on AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-amplify

I have an application deployed on AWS, the frontend (a react static site) is on Amplify and the backend (ASP.Net Core) is on Elastic Beanstalk. I can't send requests to the API because of CORS rules.

So far I've tried:

- Adding CORS to the backend following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1

It didn't worked and I can't find any guides on the internet, all of them talk about adding CORS to the S3 Bucket.

I'm pretty noob with AWS, it's my first time working on it (Came from Azure) and feel so frustated by all the clutter and the complexity involved in any operation (compared with Azure).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @myahl yes I found a solution, you have to make the configuration using the guide I linked, everything is configured in code, there is nothing to do with aws. Right now I dont have time to write a proper answer but I will do it this weekend.

Comment: CORS was working fine for me before we moved to AWS. You didn't have to do anything with .ebextensions or anything like that? I had suspected it was something to do with the nginx proxy. I'm using a single Docker container.

Comment: @myahl No, I didn't change anything in AWS, This is the configuration in my startup: https://imgur.com/a/rYCQ5X4

Comment: Not working out for me. Do you use a load balancer?

Comment: @myahl I think he didn't use a load balancer. We can't control cors rules on the load balancer.