# AWS Elastic beanstalk: ASP.NET Cors configuration not allowing hosts

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, cors, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to get an API to allow requests from an origin. As of right now nothing is getting through so allowing any origin is the goal right now and I can tighten up the access once it is working.

The API is written in ASP.net and gets deployed to elastic beanstalk. When I try and hit the API with any front end I get the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.website.com/endpoint' from origin 'http://localhost:{PORT_NUM}' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Cors Configuration in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    services.AddCors();

    // ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors(x => x
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true));

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

The endpoint is not cinfigured in any special way:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([FromBody]CreateRequest request)
{
    //...
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

I have read through the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and tried the code in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59899287/how-to-configure-cors-between-an-api-hosted-on-aws-elasticbeanstalk-and-the-fron#comment106947155_59899287).

Comment: What could be happening is that you have another error in your pipeline before it gets to the CORS middleware - the CORS error could be covering up something else. Just a theory.

Comment: Any success? Have the same issue

Answer (score -1):

You may need to setup your API Endpoint to return CORS headers.  Modify `Create` to return the following headers:

```cs
// add CORS headers
{"Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type"},
{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"},
{"Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS,POST,GET"}
```

If you're using AWS API Gateway, you'll also need to configure `DefaultCorsPreflightOptions`. I did this via CDK, but it looked like this:

```cs
DefaultCorsPreflightOptions = new CorsOptions
{
   AllowHeaders = new []{ "Content-Type", "X-Amz-Date", "Authorization", "X-Api-Key" },
   AllowMethods = new []{ "OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE" },
   AllowCredentials =  true,
   AllowOrigins = new []{ "*" }
}
```

These commits from my demo repo might help:  https://github.com/ppittle/cdk-talk-2021/commit/19ded54e689c15cf5a23d9f461b97c0519decca5#diff-b30e8e7c0dda60b0346a05a7243f8ccb93397e7321e4ece9156798c5d1441131